# Crystal Reports using Report and SubReport

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Suppose I have the following:

```
public class MyObject
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public List<MySubObject> SubObjects {get; set;}
}

public class MySubObject
{
   public string SubName {get; set;}
}
```

Is there a way I can set up a report and sub report to show a list of `MyObjects` (each with a list of subreports for their respective `MySubObjects`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your class definition is missing the name of the `List<MySubObject>`:

```
public class MyObject
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public List<MySubObject> SubObjects {get; set;}
}

public class MySubObject
{
   public string SubName {get; set;}
}
```

You can loop through and populate a dataset (you don't really need to use subreports, uness your data is more complex than you've described above):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("SubReport");
foreach (MyObject myo in list_of_myobjects)
{
 foreach (MySubObject myso in myo.SubObjects)
 {
  DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
  dr[0] = myo.Name;
  dr[1] = myso.SubName;
  dt.Rows.Add();
  ds.Tables.Add(dt);
 }
}
```

Then point your crystal report datasource at the dataset:

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
CrystalReport1 objRpt = new CrystalReport1();
objRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[1]);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Comment: The example I gave was constructed for the question - those aren't my real classes, but are similar. I have never used datasets. Up until now, I've been working with `IEnumerable<T>` where T is `MyObject`. Are there more advantages to creating a datatable first, and then using that as the report source?

Comment: From what i understand you are limited as to what you can pass as the report source. You would normally provide connection details for some form of database- but based on what you want to pass, a dataset is the only thing that springs to mind

Comment: I should also add- depending on the complexity and flexibility you desire you don't have to hardcode the column names- you can iterate through properties of your class

Comment: Technically, I'm working with Entity Framework 4, but Crystal Reports does not seem to play nice, so I've been using simple intermediate objects. From those, I'm able to drag and drop my items onto the report pretty easily. I don't want to have to set up reports programatically - that would be bad for maintainability.